# Separating record returned from function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a function that returns two parameters as an anonymous composite type via [output parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-OUTPUT-PARAMETERS).

I can access the individual columns with a query like this:

```
# select * from guess_user('Joe','Bloggs');
 confidence | matchid 
------------+---------
   0.142857 |    1121
```

Now I want to combine the output from this function with some data:

```
# select firstname,lastname from users limit 5;
 firstname | lastname 
-----------+----------
 Adam      | Smith
 Amy       | Peters
 Annette   | Bloggs
 Annie     | Mills
 Amanda    | Hibbins
```

I am looking for a query that will output the following:

```
 firstname | lastname | confidence | matchid 
-----------+----------+------------+---------
 Adam      | Smith    |            | 
 Amy       | Peters   |            | 
 Annette   | Bloggs   |            | 
 Annie     | Mills    |            | 
 Amanda    | Hibbins  |            |
```

With the confidence and matchid columns filled out using the results of calling guess_user with the names from that row.

My current closest effort is:

```
# select firstname, lastname, guess_user(firstname, lastname) from users limit 5;
```

Which returns:

```
 firstname | lastname  |  guess_user   
-----------+-----------+---------------
 Angela    | Abbott    | (0.285714,3)
 Amy       | Allan     | (0.285714,4)
 Annette   | Allison   | (0.285714,5)
 Annie     | Ashworth  | (0.285714,6)
 Amanda    | Baird     | (0.285714,7)
```

Is there a way to split the guess_user output into separate columns?

Comment: In case it's helpful for anyone wanting to experiment, here's a function that will return the same record type as the one I'm using:

create or replace function guess_user ( firstname varchar, lastname varchar, OUT confidence real, OUT matchid integer ) as $$ BEGIN matchid := 1; confidence := 0.5; RETURN; END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: Would it be possible to implement this as a view instead? http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createview.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

combining depesz and fazal's answers this seems to work:

```
select firstname, lastname, (guess_user(firstname, lastname)).*
from users
limit 5
```

Comment: To add a little more information, per http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rowtypes.html "To access a field of a composite column, one writes a dot and the field name, much like selecting a field from a table name. In fact, it's so much like selecting from a table name that you often have to use parentheses to keep from confusing the parser."

Answer (score 2):

Simply make it like this:

```
select firstname, lastname, x.confidence, x.matchid
from 
(
select firstname, lastname, guess_user(firstname, lastname) as x
from users
limit 5
) q;
```

Comment: You have to use parenthesis around to access composite type fields:

select firstname, lastname, (x).confidence, (x).matchid

Otherwise, get this error: "missing FROM-clause entry for table "x""

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your function [to return a set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xfunc-sql.html#AEN40353) - the last example is identical to the functionality you are asking for.

Comment: `RETURNS SETOF record` to indicate that the function returns multiple rows instead of just one.  They aren't tied to an existing table, you could return a `TYPE` instead if you preferred. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go but I still couldn't seem to put the function in the right place to get it to work. This page:

http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/11/03/waiting-for-84-pl-srf-functions-in-selects/

Seems to suggest it's a limitation of postgres, which is solved on 8.4 (I'm running 8.3.8).

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone comes along and corrects me, I believe that the answer is that it's currently not possible in 8.3 but can be done in Postgres 8.4.

http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2008/11/03/waiting-for-84-pl-srf-functions-in-selects/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to parenthesize the "x" in depesz's solution, to distinguish the composite record value from a table, so you don't get the message:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "x"
```

At least I do on 9.0.2.